# Java connection to postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, maven

first time asking a question here, so forgive me if I do something wrong.

I have a connection to a postgresql in java like so:

A Maven xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>SQL_Database</groupId>
<artifactId>SQL_Database</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

 </dependencies>


</project>
```

3 classes: Connect.java:

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class Connect {

        private Connection conn;

        public Connect(){
        }

        public void setConnection(String database, String user, String password){
            String format = String.format("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/%s", database);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("user", user);
            props.put("password", password);
            try {
                this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(format, props);
                this.conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            } catch (SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public Connection getConnection(){
            return this.conn;
         }

        public void closeConnection() {
            try {
                this.conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Sql.java:

```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;


   class Sql {

   private Connection conn;
   private ResultSet results;

   public Sql(Connection conn) {
       this.conn = conn;
   }

   public void update(String query) {
       try {
           this.conn.prepareStatement(query).executeUpdate();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }

   public void select(String query) {
       try {
           this.results = this.conn.prepareStatement(query).executeQuery();
           getResults();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
   }
```

And Main.java:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Connect c = new Connect();
    c.setConnection("foo", "foo", "foo");
    Connection conn = c.getConnection();
    Sql sql = new Sql(conn);
    String query = <Some SQL statement>;
    sql.update(query);
    sql.select(<Some SQL statement>);
    c.closeConnection();
  }
}
```

This works perfectly, I can create tables, select stuff from those tables etc.

However, I want to have this connection in another project, so I recreated the Connect and Sql classes in that project and I added the statements in Main.java to the main class in the other project.

I can do `Connect c = new Connect();` and that works, but when I try to do `c.setConnection("foo", "foo", "foo");`, it doesn't work, Java doesn't recognize the `c` object or something.
Same thing with `sql`.

I don't understand why it works in one project, but if I do the exact same thing in another project, it doesn't work.

This is the code in my project that doesn't work:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    Connect c = new Connect();
    c.setConnection("foo", "foo", "foo");
    Connection conn = c.getConnection();
    Sql sql = new Sql(conn);
    -- Some other code that works perfectly without the above--
   }
```

PS. Sorry for the code bomb.

Comment: Can you show us the code from the project that doesn't work?  And paste the error message.

Comment: I'll add the code to my post. The error i get when I try to run it it is this:       Error:(22, 20) java: <identifier> expected                                                          Error:(22, 21) java: illegal start of type                                                                   Error:(22, 39) java: illegal start of type                                                                     Error:(22, 48) java: illegal start of type

Comment: You've got `<db_name` instead of `<db_name>`.  You also need quotes around the strings.  If that's not it, you'll need to paste the actual code rather than "pseudo code", since it sounds like a rogue character somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it was pseudo code, sorry. I've corrected my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your code isn't inside a method.

It should be something like:-

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public void connect() { // <-- Method declaration
        Connect c = new Connect();
        c.setConnection("foo", "foo", "foo");
        Connection conn = c.getConnection();
        Sql sql = new Sql(conn);
        //-- Some other code that works perfectly without the above--
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked!